# How would I express that I'm an American with Indian heritage?

Tags: translation, word-choice, english-to-japanese

I'm an American citizen, born and raised here, who speaks English as my only native language. Both my parents are Indian and I look Indian. What is a natural way of conveying all this? Saying just that I'm an アメリカ人 seems like it might cause confusion, but saying that I'm an インド人 doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Is there any word in English that conveys all this?

Comment: @jarmanso7 I don't think they expected it to be one word. They wanted to know the natural way to say it.

Comment: @Leebo fair point, yet "American with Indian heritage" does not sound like an idiomatic expression, it's pretty literal.

Comment: @jarmanso7 That's true, it's not particularly elegant. In English I wouldn't usually bother to specify that I'm Indian-American, since it's usually pretty evident from my look and name. I suppose I'm mainly concerned that saying just that I'm an American would be somewhat confusing, and I'm not confident in my ability to explain the details of my circumstances naturally.

Comment: @Mycroft I might have come across as a pedant. I apologize. I don't know either America nor Japan particularly well, but given that the first country is more diverse in cultures and races than the second, it makes sense to be concerned with specifying your heritage to avoid confusion while in Japan or talking to Japanese people.  Probably "Indian-American" is the answer to my question, anyway.

Comment: @jarmanso7 No worries man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be インド[系]{けい}アメリカ人. It says nothing about your linguistic abilities, of course.